# Javascript Performance this. vs varname. for accessing properties

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Is there a performance difference when you have code like

```
var Base64{
encode : function(a){
    ...
},
decode : function(b){
    ...
}
}
```

Inside the class Base64, should properties and functions be accessed using **this.encode()** or using **Base64.encode()**

Is there any difference in performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *don't bother with this micro optimisation* and use `this` because it makes your code more maintainable.

What if you want to change `Base64` to `base_64`? Better to change it one place only :)

Comment: that's a good approach. just needs discipline to make sure the context is always `Base64`.